# Automatic add space if user enters number(any digit)

Tags: functions, jquery, ajax, javascript, html

I have one input field in that I need to check that if user enters any digit then it automatic add spaces i.e.

When someone enter a phone number like 0499287909 then in string should change the format to 0499 287 909 with spaces.

So what can I do Please help me. I'm working in Wordpress here's my code:

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo  esc_url( get_post_type_archive_link('job_listing' ) ); ?>">
    <label>
        <span class="screen-reader-text"><?php _e( 'Search for:', 'listify' ); ?></span>
        <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search', 'listify' ); ?>" value=""
        name="search_keywords" title="<?php echo esc_attr_e( 'Search for:', 'listify' ); ?>" onkeyup="alert('asdhjb');" />
    </label>
    <button type="submit" class="search-submit"><i class="ion-search-strong"></i></button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of questions is better asked on StackOverflow community.

Maybe this JS hack would help:

```
var elem = document.querySelector('.search-form input[name="search_keywords"]');
if ( null !== elem ) {
    elem.onchange = function() {
        var e = this
          , v = e.value;
        if ( ! v ) return;
        v = v.toString();
        if ( 0 === v.indexOf(0) ) {
            v = v.substring(1);
            var zero = true;
        }
        v = v.match(/.{1,3}/g);
        v = v.toString().replace(/,/g, ' ');
        if ( zero && v ) v = "0" + v;
        if ( v ) elem.value = v;
    }
}
```

Add it to your main JS file or to the footer using [`wp_footer`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_footer) action hook